# Does the shape of json object have to match when you make a mongoose query with findOne?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to findOne document that matches but the user returns as null when I remove the field imageUrl. Which in turn creates duplicate copies of my user when they log in. What am I misunderstanding here?

```
User.findOne({
            google: {
                id: profile.id,
                imageUrl: profile.photos[0].value,  // When I comment this out, existingUser is null.
                }
            })
            .then((existingUser) => {
            console.log('discovered', existingUser);
                if (existingUser) {
                    console.log('FOUND ONE!');
                    return done(null, existingUser);
                } else {
                    console.log('DID NOT FIND!');
                    new User({
                        google: {
                            id: profile.id,
                            imageUrl: profile.photos[0].value
                        }
                    })
                        .save()
                        .then(user => done(null, user));
                }
            });
```

What I am trying to do is findOne document based on the google id only.

Comment: Can you show the document example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the element (field) must complete match the value (including the sequence of the elements (fields)).

**Your query must look like this (it means that `google` element must have the subelement `id` equal to `profile.id`):**

```
{
    "google.id": profile.id
}
```

---

Your query means that `google` element must be equal to `{id: profile.id, imageUrl: profile.photos[0].value}`.

When you removing the `imageUrl` element, your query then is:

```
{
    google: { id: profile.id }
}
```

It means that `google` element must be equal to `{ id: profile.id }`.